# How can I filter a list using generics and Linq extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, filter

I'm trying to write a generic Filter extension method for a system, such that I can call filter on any List and pass in a Dictionary of field names and their values to filter on.

I currently have a method for each type in my system, but I'm trying to consolidate to one method.

Here is what I have so far...simplified so it's only text searching:

```
public static List<T> Filter<T>(this List<T> model, string json)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> searchFields = (Dictionary<string, object>)ser.DeserializeObject(json);

        foreach (var key in searchFields.Keys)
        {               
            // How do I perform the search?               
        }

        return model;
    }
```

My current filter is a switch statement over each key and checking each field as follows:

```
switch(key) 
{
    case "Description":
        list = list.Where(x => x.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchFields[key].ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
                    break;
}
```

How do I access the property on the generic object to filter it? I assume I need reflection somehow, but I don't know the syntax.

I'm looking for something like:

```
list = list.where(listobject.getField(key).contains(value))
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, you are trying to find out how to basically do this via reflection `obj.field == value` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like that inside your `foreach` loop

```
 model.Where(m => typeof(T).GetProperty(key).GetValue(m, null)==searchFields[key]);
```

Comment: welcome but you are not idiot because u asked this question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var key in searchFields.Keys)
{               
    model.Where(m => typeof(T).GetProperty(key).GetValue(m, null).Equals(SearchFields[key], StringComparison.OrdianlIgnoreCase);         
}

return model.ToList();
```

Comment: That wouldn't do, it does not ever compare the value of the member with the value in the dictionary.